# Calculating the closest future periodic payment date in SQL

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

I'm working on an application that deals with periodic payments
Payments are done fortnightly i.e.

- payment 1: 2009-06-01
- payment 2: 2009-06-15
- payment 3: 2009-06-29

and now I need a SQL statement that can calculate the closest next payment date from a given date in the WHERE clause

i.e.
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE someDate < *[CALCULATE NEXT PAY DATE FROM A GIVEN DATE]*

If I were to do this in C# I would go

```
static DateTime CalculateNextPayDateFrom(DateTime fromDate)
{
    var firstEverPayment = new DateTime(2009, 6, 1);
    var nextPayment = firstEverPayment;

    while (nextPayment < fromDate)
    {
        nextPayment += new TimeSpan(14, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    return nextPayment;
}
```

So if I do

```
Console.WriteLine(CalculateNextPayDateFrom(new DateTime(2009, 6, 12)).ToString());
Console.WriteLine(CalculateNextPayDateFrom(new DateTime(2009, 6, 20)).ToString());
```

output will be

```
15/06/2009 12:00:00 a.m.
29/06/2009 12:00:00 a.m.
```

but I'm totally stuck when I have to do this in SQL.

Can anyone give me a hand on this? I am using SQL Server 2005

UPDATE: 
By the way, I forgot to mention that last payment date is not available in database, it has to be calculated at runtime.

Comment: Do you have the payment dates in a table already? Can you give a sample schema? Are you just trying to work out the next date itself or return all entries from a table between two dates?

Comment: If its "easy" in c#, can you post that code and then we can come up with a SQL version...

Comment: Do you have a rule that states what the actual payment date is? If its fortnightly do you have the last payment date? Or the first payment date to calculate the fortnightly from? Otherwise there is no way of knowing if the next one is this week or next week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do the calculation properly you need what I would refer to as the reference date e.g. the date from which you start the 2 week cycle from. (in your code thats the firstEverPayment declaration)

Given that you can datediff the number of days between now and the reference to get the number of days.
Divide by 14, but round down using Floor (e.g. work out how many 2 week intervals have already occured)
Add 1 - to move forward a two week interval. 
(You can skip the add 1 by using Ceiling, not floor)
Multiply by 14 - to get the day count
Use Date Add to add those days.

Something like

select dateadd(dd, (Ceiling(datediff (dd, '1/1/09',  getdate()) /14) * 14), '1/1/09')

Where I used 1/1/09 as the reference date.

Comment: Same principle can be used to make the c# version go faster.

Answer (score 2):

how about something like this.  Grab the current day of the year, divide by 14 to get the remainder, and add the difference from 14 back to your date.  You may have to adjust the DaysOfYear to match your first payment of the year...

```
declare @mydate datetime
set @mydate = '20090607'
select  DATEADD(dd, 14 - DATEPART(dayofyear, @mydate) % 14, @mydate)


set @mydate = '20090611'
select  DATEADD(dd, 14 - DATEPART(dayofyear, @mydate) % 14, @mydate)


set @mydate = '20090612'
select  DATEADD(dd, 14 - DATEPART(dayofyear, @mydate) % 14, @mydate)

set @mydate = '20090617'
select  DATEADD(dd, 14 - DATEPART(dayofyear, @mydate) % 14, @mydate)
```

Comment: interesting, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Use [`dateadd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)!

```
create procedure GetNextDate
(
    @StartDate datetime,
    @FromDate datetime
) as
begin
    select 
        dateadd(day, 
            14*cast(datediff(day, @StartDate, @FromDate) / 14 + 1 as int), 
        @StartDate)
end
```

That will find you the next pay date after `@FromDate`, with a starting date of `@StartDate`.

Comment: no this won't work, because say today is '2009-06-07' then using your logic the closest next payment date will be '2009-06-21', which is wrong. it should be '2009-06-15'

Comment: Edited to go grab the last pay date from a given date and then add 14 from there.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that last payment date is not available in database, it has to be calculated at runtime

Comment: @Eric - ye details are overrated, just for some reason code don't work without them :)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this answer while trying to solve for a way to calculate the "nearest" pay period date based on a known date that wasn't necessarily in the past.

Your solution *almost* got me there, but this is the full solution in-case anyone else is looking:

(the trick is to add a CASE/WHEN statement to check if the refDate occurs before the testDate)

so this works:

```
DECLARE @refDate DATE = '3/6/18', @testDate DATE = '4/10/18'
SELECT DATEADD(DD,(CEILING(DATEDIFF(DD, @refDate, @testDate )/14)-CASE WHEN @refDate>@testDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*14,@refDate)

Result:
Correctly returns "4/03/2018"
```

and this works:

```
DECLARE @refDate DATE = '3/6/18', @testDate DATE = '3/5/18'
SELECT DATEADD(DD,(CEILING(DATEDIFF(DD, @refDate, @testDate)/14)-CASE WHEN @refDate>@testDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*14,@refDate)

Result:
Correctly returns "2/20/2018"
```